# Netbeans project not deploying when I am on a feature branch

Tags: github, netbeans-8

I am working on a git hub repository with Netbeans 8.0.2. I am deploying the project locally using Tomcat 7.0.99. The project is running fine when I am on the master branch. But when I switch to a feature branch , the deploy is failing and I get the following message : **C:\Netbeans_workspace\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1233: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.**

The Apache Tomcat Server log is as follows:

Jan 09, 2020 4:24:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.customerdirectory.listeners.ContextListener]
org.slmn.DbObjectNotFoundException: Usern: No usern record for null
    at com.customerdirectory.Usern.findByEmail(Usern.java:939)
    at com.customerdirectory.listeners.ContextListener.contextInitialized(ContextListener.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5720)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Update your question with the underlying error that is shown in the Tomcat log. Without that information your question can't be answered.

Comment: @skomisa updated

Comment: To be clear, that is the exception (`org.slmn.DbObjectNotFoundException`) which is written to the Tomcat log when your deployment fails? Can you add a little more background information to your question?

Comment: Yes , the error that I updated is all I see after I run the project. There is no difference between the master branch and the feature branch atleast in the source packages. The only difference is in the static HTML content. It boggles my mind that it won't run. " I think this error often means that you're compiling your classes against one version of a library, but then are running them using a different (earlier or later) version. Check all the libraries you're using in both places o make sure everything is up to date." I read this in another forum. I hope it makes sense to you